# spacy : How to add words and their attributes to the vocabulary (vocab)?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

When a word is added to spacy's vocab,
some information such as lemma and tag need to be added as well in order to use the [linguistic features](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features).

How can I add this features to the vocab and are these changes made temporarily or for each time I call spacy?

---

I could not find any information around [the vocab source](https://spacy.io/api/vocab) that tell me how to *set* the words (not their vectors).

So far, I am checking, wether a word is in the vocab by calling

```py
word = "apple"
word in list(nlp.vocab.strings)
```

since `word in nlp.vocab, nlp.vocab.has_vector(word), nlp.vocab.get_vector(word)` always give me `False` as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The tag and lemma are not part of the vocabulary because the `Vocab` entries (`Lexeme`s) only contain context-independent features. See: https://spacy.io/api/lexeme

You can set the tag and lemma on a `Token` in a `Doc`, not on a `Lexeme`.

Note also that `nlp.vocab.strings` is not the words in the vocab, but the words/labels/etc. in the `StringStore`. `nlp.vocab` is the `Vocab` with `Lexeme` entries.

Both `nlp.vocab` and `nlp.vocab.strings` should be thought of as caches that lexemes and strings are added to as needed, so whether an item is currently in `nlp.vocab` or `nlp.vocab.strings` mainly indicates whether it's been seen before and not much else. `nlp.vocab` starts out nearly empty each time `nlp` is loaded and is extended as texts are processed.

Comment: Thank you for that deep answer! Do I have to set the tag and lemma each time a ```Doc``` is created or is there a way to add the information once and for all to spacy? 
Maybe there is a dictionary which spacy uses to search for e.g. the lemma for each word and that can be changed.

Comment: In general the tag and the lemma depend on the use of each token in context, so they're set each time a doc is created. But if you want to set them in a rule-based way, you could potentially use an `attribute_ruler` to do this.